# Extending ShoppingCartInfo object to add a new Tax Class in Kentico CMS

Tags: c#, kentico

I need to add ZIP code as a new property by which you can define a tax class in Kentico.

I know that I would need to create two new tables in the database - one to store the zip codes and their ID, and one to store tax rates for ZIP codes with a foreign key to ZIPID and a foreign key to TaxClassID - but I don't know what all objects and controls in the Kentico project are involved with the process of assigning tax classes to products when they are added to the cart.

So:

1. What objects do I need to extend to assign my new tax rates to a tax class?
2. What user controls do I need to modify in order calculate the tax price and total price of products when they are added to a user's cart?

**UPDATE 1:**

I just need to figure out how to bind data to my shopping cart controls from a custom table called TaxClassZIP (just like COM_TaxClassCountry and COM_TaxClassState).

Some connections I've made:

The CMSModules_Ecommerce_Controls_ShoppingCart_ShoppingCartContent class inherits from ShoppingCartStep, which has a property called ShoppingCart.  The ShoppingCart property appears to be exposing properties of the ShoppingCartInfo class.  One of these properties is called ContentTable, which is DataTable object that seems to contain the data for the shopping cart.  If this is true, then I believe I need some way to modify this table to include my new tax rates (or do more than that if the data table is including a computed value).

**UPDATE 2:**

[This article](http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/how-can-i-extend-a-shopping-cart%E2%80%99s-content-table-) looks like it will point me towards the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally, I was wanting to add-on to the built-in tax classes of Kentico.  I thought I could do this by inheriting from the TaxClassInfo class and defining a new field for ZIPCodeID, then overriding the methods of the TaxClassInfoProvider class to add ZIPCodeID as a parameter for calculating taxes.

However, the classes for tax classes aren't modeled the way I was expecting, and I can't really make sense of where all the data is being related among the tax classes, the shopping cart and all the other related ecommerce classes since I don't have access to the source code.

So instead, I just created a custom TaxClassInfoProvider class and overrode the GetTaxesInternal() method per [this webinar from Kentico](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/e-commerce-scenarios-with-kentico-7).

One of the files in the code samples at the bottom of the page pretty-much had this already built:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using CMS.Ecommerce;
using CMS.SettingsProvider;
using CMS.SiteProvider;
using CMS.GlobalHelper;

/// <summary>
/// Sample tax class info provider. 
/// Can be registered either by replacing the TaxClassInfoProvider.ProviderObject (uncomment the line in SampleECommerceModule.cs) or through cms.extensibility section of the web.config
/// </summary>
public class CustomTaxClassInfoProvider : TaxClassInfoProvider
{
    #region "Example: Custom taxes calculation"

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns DataSet with all the taxes which should be applied to the shopping cart items.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cart">Shopping cart</param>
    protected override DataSet GetTaxesInternal(ShoppingCartInfo cart)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        // Create an empty taxes table
        DataTable table = GetNewTaxesTable();

        // Build taxes table 
        // ------------------------
        // Please note:         
        // Taxes table is built manually for the purpose of this example, however you can build it from the response of a tax calculation service as well.
        // All the data which might be required for the calculation service is stored in the ShoppingCartInfo object, e.g.:
        // - use AddressInfoProvider.GetAddresInfo(cart.ShoppingCartBillingAddressID) to get billing address info
        // - use AddressInfoProvider.GetAddresInfo(cart.ShoppingCartShippingAddressID) to get shipping address info        
        // etc.
        // ------------------------
        foreach (ShoppingCartItemInfo item in cart.CartItems)
        {
            // Get SKU properties
            string skuNumber = item.SKU.SKUNumber.ToLowerCSafe();
            int skuId = item.SKUID;

            switch (skuNumber)
            {
                // Tax for product A (20%)
                case "a":
                    AddTaxRow(table, skuId, "Tax A", 20);
                    break;

                // Taxes for product B (11% and 10%)
                case "b":
                    AddTaxRow(table, skuId, "Tax B1", 11);
                    AddTaxRow(table, skuId, "Tax B2", 10);
                    break;

                // Zero tax for product C (0%)
                case "c":
                    break;

                // The same tax for all other products (5%)
                default:
                    AddTaxRow(table, skuId, "Tax C", 5);
                    break;

            }
        }

        // Return built dataset with the taxes
        ds.Tables.Add(table);
        return ds;
    }

    #region "Private methods"

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an empty taxes table.
    /// </summary>    
    private DataTable GetNewTaxesTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        // Add required columns
        table.Columns.Add("SKUID", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("TaxClassDisplayName", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("TaxValue", typeof(double));

        // Add optional columns
        //table.Columns.Add("TaxIsFlat", typeof(bool));
        //table.Columns.Add("TaxIsGlobal", typeof(bool));
        //table.Columns.Add("TaxClassZeroIfIDSupplied", typeof(bool));

        return table;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Creates tax row which holds the data of the tax which should be applied to the given SKU.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="taxTable">Tax table the row should be added to.</param>
    /// <param name="skuId">SKU ID</param>
    /// <param name="taxName">Tax name</param>
    /// <param name="taxValue">Tax value</param>
    /// <param name="taxIsFlat">Indicates if the tax value is flat or relative. By default it is false (= relative tax)</param>
    /// <param name="taxIsGlobal">Indicates if the tax value is in global main currency or in site main currency. By default it is false (= tax value is in site main currency).</param>    
    /// <param name="taxIsGlobal">Indicates if the tax is zero if customer's registration ID is supplied. By default it is false (= tax is not zero if customer's tax registration ID is supplied).</param>    
    private void AddTaxRow(DataTable taxTable, int skuId, string taxName, double taxValue, bool taxIsFlat, bool taxIsGlobal, bool zeroTaxIfIDSupplied)
    {
        DataRow row = taxTable.NewRow();

        // Set required columns
        row["SKUID"] = skuId;
        row["TaxClassDisplayName"] = taxName;
        row["TaxValue"] = taxValue;

        // Set optional columns
        //row["TaxIsFlat"] = taxIsFlat;
        //row["TaxIsGlobal"] = taxIsGlobal;
        //row["TaxClassZeroIfIDSupplied"] = taxIsGlobal;

        taxTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Creates tax row which holds the data of the tax which should be applied to the given SKU.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="taxTable">Tax table the row should be added to.</param>
    /// <param name="skuId">SKU ID</param>
    /// <param name="taxName">Tax name</param>
    /// <param name="taxValue">Tax value</param>
    private void AddTaxRow(DataTable taxTable, int skuId, string taxName, double taxValue)
    {
        AddTaxRow(taxTable, skuId, taxName, taxValue, false, false, false);
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion
}
```

After I found this, I created a very simple 3-column table in SQL Server with ID, ZIP, and TaxRate.

Then, I made some modifications to the above code to get access to tax rates and the current customer's address info using an address info provider:

```
AddressInfo customerAddress = AddressInfoProvider.GetAddressInfo(cart.ShoppingCartShippingAddressID);
```

After that, it was all a matter of filling a dataset with my zip code tax rates, then passing the appropriate tax rate to the AddTaxRow() method.